# How can you keep a Powershell script running continuously with TaskScheduler?

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a (dumbed down for here) Powershell script that I want to run when a user logs in (actually through auto login) that I want it to be **always** running.

```
$i = 0
$max = 5
$f = "D:\VirtualBox-Powershell\out.txt"
do {
    $i += 1
    Add-Content -Path $f -Value $((Get-Date).ToString())
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
while ($i -lt $max)
exit $i
```

Yes, I’m aware this will stop after 5 seconds.  My actual code is in a continuous loop.  I’m using TaskScheduler to start my script after login.  Theoretically that should be enough.  But the script stops for some unknown reason.  It’s either a bug in the script or something else is killing the process.

So I added a trigger to attempt to run the script every minute (which for testing purposes 5 seconds is plenty).  When I right click my task and select Run, the script sure enough modifies the file.  The task shows running and after 5 seconds I refresh and it shows ready.

But when the trigger fires (the last Run Time shows it started at the correct time), and I refresh it *immediately* shows Ready.

In both runs the exit code is Ox 1

I’ve tried starting the script by running the ps1 file directly, as well as using C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe and passing in the script as a parameter.

I’ve had some form of this issue for years, and have never found a decent workaround.  I’m hoping someone here does.

Windows 10, btw

Comment: Why does the script need to be always running? What problem are you solving?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart it’s “catching” commands I’m sending to this machine and then executing them.

Comment: Insufficient detail for me to comment further.